# haproxy 1.5 issue with reqrep when # is part of URI

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to rewrite a URL with haproxy, but when the URI contains a "#" in the string, haproxy cuts off the rest.

***Example:***

Incoming URL: http://foo.com/app1/abc?id=1&date=2016-07-06#access_token

The Goal is to Rewrite URL to:  http://foo.com/abc?id=1&date=2016-07-06#access_token (notice the "app1" is dropped)

***This is the rule I am using, but truncates the resulting URL when it encounters "#"***

reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)l2[/]?(.*)     \1\2

***The HAproxy log: (Notice it truncated anything after the #)***

Aug  4 16:06:20 localhost haproxy[5098]: xx.xx.x.xxx:61679 [04/Aug/2016:16:06:18.252] http app1/app1 0/0/0/428/2115 200 10880953 - - ---- 3/3/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /app1/abc?id=1&date=2016-07-06 HTTP/1.1"

Any advise on this?

Comment: RFC 2396 section 4.1 - When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, **it is not part of a URI**, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

Comment: Remove the `reqrep` rule and you shoud find that the `#` and following text was never there -- HAProxy isn't removing it.  Browsers are not supposed to send fragments to the server.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That makes sense now, so I will have to ensure "#" are not in the URI to begin with or they will simply not make it to the backend servers. The good news is that we are in control of that.